# in-place processing of a Metal texture

Tags: ios, macos, metal

Is it possible to process an `MTLTexture` in-place without `osx_ReadWriteTextureTier2`?

It seems like I can set two texture arguments to be the same texture. Is this supported behavior?

Specifically, I don't mind not having texture caching update after a write. I just want to in-place (and sparsely) modify a 3d texture. It's memory prohibitive to have two textures. And it's computationally expensive to copy the entire texture, especially when I might only be updating a small portion of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the documentation, regardless of feature availability, it is invalid to declare two separate texture arguments (one read, one write) in a function signature and then set the same texture for both.

Any Mac that supports `osx_GPUFamily1_v2` supports function texture read-writes (by declaring the texture with `access::read_write`).

The distinction between "Tier 1" (which has no explicit constant) and `osx_ReadWriteTextureTier2` is that the latter supports additional pixel formats for read-write textures.

If you determine that your target Macs don't support the kind of texture read-writes you need (because you need to deploy to OS X 10.11 or because you're using an incompatible pixel format for the tier of machine you're deploying to), you could operate on your texture one plane at a time, reading from your 3D texture, writing to a 2D texture, and then blitting the result back into the corresponding region in your 3D texture. It's more work, but it'll use much less than double the memory.

Comment: Could you link to the docs? I didn't see anything when I looked. Thanks!

Comment: It's a note in the Function Resource Read-Writes section of [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/WhatsNewiniOS10tvOS10andOSX1012/WhatsNewiniOS10tvOS10andOSX1012.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014221-CH14-SW1)